# Me da error si alguien me puede revisar el codigo

Tags: javascript

Implementar la función `calcularImpuestos`, de forma recursiva.

Retornar la suma total con los decimales incluidos.

La función recibirá boletas/facturas con los impuestos anuales por la casa, aunque pueden haber boletas vacías (por ende no son array), por lo que tendremos que validar eso.

Sabiendo esto, si la persona no tiene impuestos, debes retornar false, si tiene impuestos debes sumarlos y si no es una boleta/factura (array), debes devolver "error".

Si no hay inconvenientes, devolverlos para que sepa el total que debe pagar.

```
const calcularImpuestos = (factura, i = 0, acc = 0) => {    
          if(!Array.isArray(factura)) return "Error"
          if(factura.length === 0) return false
        
        
          return factura[i] = factura[i] + calcularImpuestos(factura.slice(1))
        }
```

Comment: Tal y como lo tienes esa función sólo devuelve "Error", false o la concatenación de las facturas más false. ¿Qué has intentado, realmente?

Comment: Cuál es el error?,  y agrega lo que has hecho tu pregunta parece una lista de compras (Quiero esto, esto y esto), aquí no hacemos tareas.

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y pon un título descriptivo a tu pregunta. Si alguien llega a tener un problema parecido (que de hecho no sabemos cuál es el problema, porque no lo comentas), ¿cómo encontrará tu pregunta si se titula "Me da error si alguien me puede revisar el codigo"? Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.